# Calculate ϴ dependent on n for an algorithm with constant c

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

I want to calculate ϴ dependent on n for this algorithm:

```
for (k = n; k < c; k++){
    j = 1;
    while(j < n){
        j++;
    }
```

n is the parameter. c is a constant.

I calculated the amount of operations to (c-n)*(n-1). But now I don't now how to deal with c.

Comment: What is $\Theta$ if you fill in some arbitrary number (e.g. 5) for $c$? What is $\Theta$ if you fill in some other arbitrary number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I calculated the amount of operations to (c-n)*(n-1)

Not quite. If $n > c$ then the cost is not negative: it should be $(n-1) \max(c-n, 0) = \Theta(n) \max(c-n, 0)$. When $n$ is large (and in particular when $n > c$) what does this reduce to?

Comment: I am assuming "Θ(n) max(c−n,0)" is Θ(n)*max(c−n,0)? For a large n this would reduce to 0. So Θ(1)?

Comment: Almost. $\Theta(0)$.